# git push hangs when trying to initialize as new repo on github

Tags: git, github

I've got a local repo that I'd like to push to github for the first time. What I've tried:

```
git init -b main
git add . 
git commit -m "initial commit"
gh repo create
```

Follow gh prompts to set name, visibility...
(I'm under the impression this causes the repo to be created on gh and remote is added to origin -- ie git remote add origin  -- is performed)

```
 Created repository t--/DashPCB-v2 on GitHub
✓ Added remote https://github.com/t--/DashPCB-v2.git
➜  Dash2 git:(main) git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/t--/DashPCB-v2.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/t--/DashPCB-v2.git (push)
```

Attempt to push:

```
➜  Dash2 git:(main) git push -u origin main
Enumerating objects: 1940, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1940/1940), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1937/1937), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1940/1940), 12.40 MiB | 1.18 MiB/s, done.
Total 1940 (delta 770), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0

^C
```

The repo is created on github, but contains no files (greeted by the familiar "Quick setup — if you’ve done this kind of thing before" page)

Verify I'm logged in:

```
? What account do you want to log into? GitHub.com
? You're already logged into github.com. Do you want to re-authenticate? No
```

Try again to remote add:

```
➜  Dash2 git:(main) git remote add origin https://github.com/t--/DashPCB-v2.git
error: remote origin already exists.
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I presume you have tried pushing more than once? Do you get the same behaviour every time you push? I normally create my repos in my browser on github.com, but your process looks fine.

Comment: Yes, I tried a few times. I was feeling confident that this would work and am baffled by the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
I retried with

```
git push -uv origin main
```

(with verbose option)

...and it worked

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that this would succeed when `git push -u origin main` did not. Maybe it was working all along but you were expecting to see feedback that just wasn't there.

Comment: Skepticism is your prerogative. However, I am confident that I am able to discriminate between repeated interminable pauses and empty gh repo with -u, and the clear and prompt completion of the command and the resulting appearance of the content on gh with -uv.